# TextInput Not Visible When Keyboard Is Open Expo React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, textinput, soft-keyboard

[This is my view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVyMl.png) and [this happens when I open the soft keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRntH.png), I'm running on the latest Expo and React Native, the TextInput is not seen. I don't have standalone Android and iOS folders so I cannot add things to manifest or can I?

Answer (score 0):

Use a KeyboardAvoidingView.
Here's the link to the doc https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview